# Zend GData Contacts PHP, add contact SSL error

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl

HI I am trying to do a simple contact entry in google account.

My code is simple but I am receiving the next error: "ERROR:Expected response code 200, got 403 GData forbidden The Contacts API only supports requests over SSL (https). "

I allowed the application to work over google decresing in googgle account settings the level.

Could onyone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit: I am using xampp and run from localhost. I checked all the ssl settings and are ok. Too I checked with the tool from 
https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib#windows and it pass.

```
<?php

// load Zend Gdata libraries
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Feed');



error_reporting(0);

function IngresaGoogle($cod,$nom,$ape,$dir,$tel,$doc,$espe){

// set credentials for ClientLogin authentication
$user = "xx";
$pass = "yy";

try {


  // perform login and set protocol version to 3.0
  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
$user, $pass, 'cp');
  $gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
  $gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);

  // create new entry
  $doc  = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->formatOutput = true;
  $entry = $doc->createElement('atom:entry');
  $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,
   'xmlns:atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
  $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,
   'xmlns:gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
  $doc->appendChild($entry);

  // add name element
  $name = $doc->createElement('gd:name');
  $entry->appendChild($name);
  $fullName = $doc->createElement('gd:fullName', '$nom');
  $name->appendChild($fullName);


  // insert entry
  $entryResult = $gdata->insertEntry($doc->saveXML(), 
   'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
  echo '<h2>Add Contact</h2>';
  echo 'The ID of the new entry is: ' . $entryResult->id;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR:' . $e->getMessage());
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

The code from Zden is out of date.

You must call 'http**S**://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full' instead of normal one.